# Grails remoteLink : Entire page loaded in response

Tags: ajax, grails, gsp, grails-controller

First, sorry for my bad english, I'm French.

Here the problem :

I have a template which look like this :

```
<p>
<strong>Whas this answer usefull ?</strong>
<g:remoteLink action="niceAnswer"
              class="btn rate-reply"
              update="comment-${ comment.id }"
              params="${ [commentId: comment.id, nice: true, productId: productId] }">
              Yes
</g:remoteLink>
<g:remoteLink action="niceAnswer"
              class="btn rate-reply"
              update="comment-${ comment.id }"
              params="${ [commentId: comment.id, productId: productId] }">
              No
</g:remoteLink>
```

Here the GSP for reload the fragment page :

```
<div class="rating" id="comment-${ comment.id }">
    <g:render template="affRating" model="${ [comment: comment, productId: product.id] }" />
</div>
```

Here the javascript which is generated (see via firebug) :

```
<a class="btn rate-reply" action="niceAnswer" onclick="jQuery.ajax({type:'POST',data:{'commentId': '723','nice': 'true','productId': '872'}, url:'/macsf-fronts/action/commentaire/reponse-utile',success:function(data,textStatus){jQuery('#comment-723').html(data);},error:function(XMLHttpRequest,textStatus,errorThrown){}});return false;" href="/macsf-fronts/action/commentaire/reponse-utile?commentId=723&nice=true&productId=872"> Yes </a>
```

And here the controller code which execute this action :

```
def niceAnswer() {
    def comment = DocCommentaireSite.get(params.commentId)
    if (comment && session["comment_${comment.id}"] == null) {
        if (params.nice) {
            comment.nbYesReponseUtile++
        }
        comment.nbReponseUtileVote++
        session["comment_${comment.id}"] = comment.id
        comment.save()
    }

    def product = DocProduitSite.get params.productId
    if (request.xhr) {
        log.debug "niceAnswer : All is good"
        render template: 'affRating', 
               model: [comment: comment, productId: params.productId]
    } else {
        log.debug "niceAnswer : bad behaviour"
        def slugMap = referenceService.getSlugAndParentSlug(product)
        log.info "slugMap : ${slugMap}"
        redirect controller: 'frontRequest', action: 'index', params: [slug: slugMap.slug, parentSlug: slugMap.parentSlug]
    }
        log.debug "niceAnswer : wtf ?!"
}
```

The log "All is good" is the only which is rendered.
But every time, the entire page is reloaded in the response, I really dont get why.

Thanks in advance,

Snite

Comment: what is the exact behaviour: is the page reloaded (if yes, then check, whether you have javascript errors on your page (firebug)), if the page is rendered into the div, then double check the render line. maybe you have to add `layout: ` or some `<r:layoutResources/>`. are you using grails 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the answer.

It was because of a js execution :

```
jQuery('.rating').find('.btn').click(function(e){ 
  e.preventDefault(); 
 jQuery(this).closest('div').load('?zajax=reponse'); 
});
```

This code, use by designer, was for demo, and reload the page.
Comment this code fixed the problem.

Not easy to find !

Sorry for answer only today, and thanks for yours !

Answer (score 1):

Whenever I have had this happen it was because I didn't have this on my GSP:

```
<g:javascript library="jquery" />
```

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because you didn't attach any JavaScript library as a resource to your page. So the browser fails to call the specified function and just follows the link.
To correct the situation add to your header:

```
<g:javascript library="jquery"/>
<r:layoutResources/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<g:javascript library="prototype" />
```